# Unable to trim string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am tryinf to trim a string in powershell to get a desirer value but unable to do that.

e.x string1= abc_xyz-mnq_R81
string2= abc_xyz-mnq_R82

I tried like-
string1.trim("abc_xyz-mnq_R")
Output: 81

string2.trim("abc_xyz-mnq_R")
Output:8

I got output as 81 but when I tried for string2 I got only 8.

I need to have a generic way so whatever may be before anystring_R it only trim out that number.

Comment: Please edit the _question_ and explain what you are really trying to do. Add desired outcome too. `Trim()` is usually used to remove whitespace, though via a char array any set of characters can be specified. Depending on your use case, maybe a regex would be much simpler a solution, or just using split instead.

Comment: the `.Trim()` methods _do not trim away a STRING_ ... they trim away the characters in the string. in your case, the characters would be trimmed from both ends until no more chars in the string matched any of the chars in the trim call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `-replace` to delete substrings by regex patterns

```bsh
PS> $string1="abc_xyz-mnq_R81"
PS> $string2="abc_xyz-mnq_R82"
PS> $string1 -replace "^.*_R"
81
PS> $string2 -replace "^.*_R"
82
```